# Migrate ldap to another server

Tags: 10.04, migration, ldap, 8.10

I have ubuntu(8.10) ldap server running. I am migrating from my old servers to ubuntu 10.04.2 server and I have set up almost all freshly on the new servers. How could I perfectly migrate ldap to the new server after installing ldap?.

I found the following to export and import ldap in the google:

```
slapcat -l master.ldif
slapadd -c -l master.ldif
```

Is there anything I've to do before/after using those commands?. Any precautions?

**EDIT 1**:
I could not configure ldap server freshly following the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html):
error:

```
root@station3:`# ldapadd -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com -W -f front-end.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Comment: After installing ldap when I try to import by `slapadd -c -l master.ldif
` I'm getting following error `Available database(s) do not allow slapadd`

Comment: Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

While I can't remember the exact release, OpenLDAP switched from file-based configuration to LDAP-based config sometime around the '08 releases.

If possible, I would do a test-migration and see (in a controlled environment) if your new server works as expected.

Comment: You've any idea, I've updated my question!

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Perhaps they can help over at ServerFault?